# how to properly use output parameter as variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this code

```
DECLARE @columnName varchar(25)
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @tableName as nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @PartNo as nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @value as integer

set @PartNo = 'partnumber'
set @tableName = 'sometable'

SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
                  SELECT c.name 
                  FROM sys.columns c 
                  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                  WHERE c.object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables 
                                       WHERE name  = @tableName)
                    AND c.name NOT IN ('something')

OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @columnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'select sum('+@columnName+') from checktime where partNo = '''+@PartNo+''''

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnName varchar(25), @PartNo nvarchar(30), @value int OUTPUT',
                   @columnName,
                   @PartNo,
                   @value OUTPUT

    FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @columnName
END

CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

The problem with this code is, it already outputs the variable even if I do not want to. I would like to use the code like this

```
 DECLARE @columnName varchar(25)
    DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @tableName as nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @PartNo as nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @value as integer

    set @PartNo = 'partnumber'
    set @tableName = 'sometable'
    SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
    select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
    where c.object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name  = @tableName )
    and c.name not in ('something')

    OPEN @cursor

    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @cursor INTO @columnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


    set @sql = 'select sum('+@columnName+') from checktime where partNo = '''+@PartNo+''''

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnName varchar(25), @PartNo nvarchar(30), @value int OUTPUT',
                       @columnName,
                       @PartNo,
                       @value OUTPUT

select case when @value > 0 then 'YEY' end 

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @cursor INTO @columnName
    END

    CLOSE @cursor
    DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

I am creating a stored procedure that would search if a column name is NULL, if it is, I would put it in my select statement. I am building a dynamic SQL where the output would just produce all the tables which are not null, but this task, I will just create it myself, I only want to know how can I manipulate the OUTPUT variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J

In your sp_executesql the @value parameter is not used in any way. It is useless. So you can modify your initial as follows

```
set @sql = 'select sum('+@columnName+'), 5 from CursorQ where partNo = '''+@PartNo+''' having sum('+@columnName+') > 0'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnName varchar(25), @PartNo nvarchar(30)',
                   @columnName,
                   @PartNo--, @value OUTPUT
```

You see I have placed a filtering criteria with HAVING clause

Another option is using @value parameter. You can modify the script to use @value as follows

```
set @sql = 'set @value = (select sum('+@columnName+') from CursorQ where partNo = '''+@PartNo+''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnName varchar(25), @PartNo nvarchar(30), @value int OUTPUT',
                   @columnName,
                   @PartNo, 
                   @value OUTPUT

                   if isnull(@value,0)>0
                    select @value where isnull(@value,0)>0
```

And you can realize that I assign the SUM value to output then in the following SELECT I used an IF clause checking the @value if it is not null and greater than zero (in SELECT the WHERE clause is reduntant, but you can prefer to use WHERE instead of IF)